Application to a PhD program abroad
I am in the second year of my Master's program in International Trade in a developing country and planning to apply for a PhD abroad next year. However, I’m unsure where to start. I don’t fully understand how the application process works, how to search for and contact a supervisor, or whether reaching out to one is necessary before applying. If so, I’d like to know how to find and approach potential supervisors effectively. If you’ve been in a similar situation, I’d greatly appreciate any advice or insights from your experience.

For some, but not yet enough, countries, see: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368

This is too general for an answer here. Things vary by country and in some countries, vary by university. Look at web sites for a few universities in places you would like to study.

@MisterMiyagi, the canonical question we both linked to is incomplete, covering only a few countries and missing many. The OP has not stated where they want to study. Until we know more, this can't be considered a duplicate.

@Buffy So far this is a generic request like the other. They are free to [edit] the question to clarify how it differs. If they just add a country tag, any answers respecting that should ideally also go to the canonical.
